# JPA Bidirectional OneToOne Not working

Tags: java, jpa, entity, bidirectional

I try to build a bidirectional relationship. I am using Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE with Spring Boot JPA to generate my repositories. I try to save two entities which are associated to each other, but it isnt working. I commented the test-statements which fails.

My Entites:

Driver:

```
@Entity
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Driver {

    public static final String COLUMN_CAR = "car";



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_CAR)
    private Car car;

}
```

Car:

```
@Entity
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = Driver.COLUMN_CAR)
    private Driver driver;

}
```

I used Spring JPA to generate repositories.

DriverRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface DriverRepository extends CrudRepository<Driver, Long> { }
```

CarRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long> { }
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class StackoverflowTest {

    @Autowired
    private DriverRepository driverRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Driver driver = driverRepository.save(new Driver());
        Car car = carRepository.save(new Car());

        driver.setCar(car);

        driverRepository.save(driver);

        /* Success, so the driver got the car */
        driverRepository.findAll().forEach(eachDriver -> Assert.assertNotNull(eachDriver.getCar()));

        /* Fails, so the car doesnt got the driver */
        carRepository.findAll().forEach(eachCar -> Assert.assertNotNull(eachCar.getDriver()));
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        Driver driver = driverRepository.save(new Driver());
        Car car = carRepository.save(new Car());

        car.setDriver(driver);

        carRepository.save(car);

        /* Success, so the car got the driver */
        carRepository.findAll().forEach(eachCar -> Assert.assertNotNull(eachCar.getDriver()));

        /* Fails, so the driver doesnt got the car */
        driverRepository.findAll().forEach(eachDriver -> Assert.assertNotNull(eachDriver.getCar()));
    }

}
```

In both tests the last statement fails. Any ideas? Thanks in Advice.

Comment: Can you post the code where you create/get both ``User`` and ``UserBan``, how you persist it and how you fetch it back from the DB ?

Comment: I changed my entities, posted my repository-classes and my unit tests. :) hope you can help my out.

Answer (score 1):

Several mistakes in what you posted.

First:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = Driver.COLUMN_CAR)
```

`mappedBy` expects the name of the **Java field/property** on the other side of the association. Not the name of the database column. It works here because both happen to have the same name.

Second:

```
carRepository.findAll().forEach(eachCar -> Assert.assertNotNull(eachCar.getDriver()));
```

That fails simply because you're doing everything in a single transaction, and you failed to properly initialize the two sides of the association. So `car.driver` is just as you initialized it: null.

Third:

```
driverRepository.findAll().forEach(eachDriver -> Assert.assertNotNull(eachDriver.getCar()));
```

You made the same mistake as before, but worse. Here, you only initialized one side of the association, but you initialized the **inverse** side of the association (the one which has the `mappedBy` attribute). So the association won't even be saved in the database, as it would have been in your previous snippet.

Comment: So the first thing was not the problem.

I dont understand why. I got Cascading enabled, so if I save them to db, I got the initialized object back from it. So why is it null?

Again. The cascading and saving to db should solve the problem? Maybe I got some big issues in understanding how the association and the cascading works. 

Could you post me a snipped that does save my problem? So I can see my mistake? :) Would be awesome.

Comment: Regarding the first thing, read again. I said: *it works here because both happen to have the same name*. So it works only because the field and the column have the same name. What is expected is still a filed name, not a column name. The problem is that you think that *if I save them to db, I got the initialized object back from it*. That's incorrect. If you save something, JPA stores it, as is, in its persistence context (aka first-level cache).